# Search on Multiple index gives wrong total_found Result ( Sphinx 2.X )

Tags: sphinx

I am not sure, I am right or wrong.

I have two index x_person , y_person .

If i query on x_person

```
SELECT * FROM x_person WHERE is_active = 0 LIMIT 0,1;

mysql> show meta;
+---------------+--------+
| Variable_name | Value  |
+---------------+--------+
| total         | 1000   |
| total_found   | 131541 |
| time          | 0.005  |
+---------------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And Querying in y_person :

```
SELECT * FROM y_person WHERE is_active = 0 LIMIT 0,1;Show meta;

mysql> show meta;
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| total         | 1000  |
| total_found   | 34733 |
| time          | 0.002 |
+---------------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Assuming if i select x_person and y_person index together, the total_match should be 131541+34733 = 166274

```
SELECT * FROM x_person,y_person WHERE is_active = 0 LIMIT 0,1;


mysql> show meta;
+---------------+--------+
| Variable_name | Value  |
+---------------+--------+
| total         | 1000   |
| total_found   | 165552 |
| time          | 0.008  |
+---------------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here i got total_found = 165552. Can any one explain Why this is not showing same 'total_found' Number ?

Comment: @MoyedAnsari , Its Sphinx Query and its not related to MySql.I tagged this question is for sphinx.

Comment: The total rows found for that query would likely be 131541*34733 (ie, every possible combination of the rows from the 2 tables), but that sql is likely invalid as both tables seem to have a column called is_active and you have not specified which one you are referring to.

Comment: I am referring to the last result, In the last result i selected both the index (x_person and y_person ) . So i assume the 'total_found' should be the sum of first and second 'total_found'. @Kickstart

Comment: Umm Kickstart, that is a **SphinxQL** query, not Mysql. Sphinx'es comma joins are effectivly a **UNION**, not a CROSS-JOIN like in regular SQL. So the total_found of both is basically the **sum** of the seperate - ie 131541+34733 ~= 165552 (only ~= because total_found is often an approximation, not an exact figure)

Comment: Ah, sorry. Only just realised used to contain the mysql tag, hence the confusion!

Comment: Interesting. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sphinx searches both of those indexes, and makes a 'UNION' of the results. Adding them together.

```
131541 + 34733 = 166274. Which is roughly 165552
```

The slight difference could be down to

1. total_found is often an **approximation**. So wont exactly add up.
2. **Duplicate ids**. If the same doc_id, is found in each index, it will only be returned ONCE in the final resultset. total_found will reflect this 'deduplication' (but again only approximatly)

Can make it less of an approximation, by raising `max_matches`, it its big enough to encompass the whole resultset, the figure will be exact.

Comment: i was querying x_person and y_person and it had same document id. :) Thank you @barryhunter. Tested for less than 1000 records to avoid the max_matches issue.Really thank you for good support.

Comment: If u feel it is useful for others please Click up for the Question . I thnk many people had this same issue.